# Merging multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays..Array1 and Array 2.
Both the array contain 2 records.

Now i need to merge both the array inside one array..

In my second array i am getting below two fields from U_data.

```
[totalcharge] => 15
 [RoadTotal] => 15
```

Now i need to merge this fields in first array..

Please help me, i need to merge multiple arrays. Below is the problem:

I have tried something like this...but i cannot achieve my expected output..

```
$abc = array_merge($content,$modecost);

**Array 1** 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 2046
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4361
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 3170
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4670
                )

        )

)


**Array 2** 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

)
```

Ultimately I would like it to look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 2046
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4361
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
            [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 3170
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4670
                )

        )

)
```

Output of array_merge_recursive

i try below code but getting different result as i want...

```
   $array3   = array_merge_recursive($content, $modecost);         
             echo"<pre>"; print_r($array3);
             exit();
```

**i want all the U_data fields inside one array  not in different array...**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 2046
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4361
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 3170
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4670
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: try `array_merge_recursive`

Comment: hi sir i added my output of array_merge_recursive in my question......but not getting my result as i want..plz help ..

Comment: @testdesk  Check my answer.

Comment: @testdesk plz check my ans. kinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_merge_recursive in proper way.

```
$arr1 = array(
            '0' => array(
                'u_data' => array(
                    'Mode' => 'Rail',
                    'TotalCost' => 150,),
                '0' => array(
                    'CostSavingRoutes' => 1,
                    'RailCostSaving' => 150,
                    'Costsavingshipments' => 2,),
                'origin_city' => array(
                    'origin_pcode' => 2046,),
                'dest_city' => array(
                    'dest_pcode' => 4361,),
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'u_data' => array(
                    'Mode' => 'Rail',
                    'TotalCost' => 150,),
                '0' => array(
                    'CostSavingRoutes' => 1,
                    'RailCostSaving' => 150,
                    'Costsavingshipments' => 2,),
                'origin_city' => array(
                    'origin_pcode' => 3170,),
                'dest_city' => array(
                    'dest_pcode' => 4670,),
            ),
);
$arr2 =array(
        '0' => array(
            'u_data' => array(
                'totalcharge' => 15,
                'RoadTotal' => 15,)
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'u_data' => array(
                'totalcharge' => 15,
                'RoadTotal' => 15,),
        )
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) { 
    $final[] = array_merge_recursive($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);    
}


echo "<pre>".print_r($arr1,1)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($arr2,1)."</pre>";
echo "<pre> Final  ---> ".print_r($final,1)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$res = Hash::merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: Should really be using `Hash::merge()` instead of `Set::merge()`.

Comment: `Set` has been [deprecated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) since CakePHP 2.2 so shouldn't be used unless using an older version of Cake.

Answer (score 0):

I thought array_merge_recursive would work but it doesn't seem to work like that.

```
<?php
    $array1Entry1 = array(
        'u_data' => array(
            'Mode' => 'Rail',
            'TotalCost' => 150
        )
    );
    $array1Entry2 = array(
        'u_data' => array(
            'Mode' => 'Rail',
            'TotalCost' => 150
        )
    );
    $array2Entry1 = array(
        'u_data' => array(
            'totalcharge' => 15,
            'RoadTotal' => 15
        )
    );
    $array2Entry2 = array(
        'u_data' => array(
            'totalcharge' => 15,
            'RoadTotal' => 15
        )
    );

$array1 = array($array1Entry1, $array1Entry2);
$array2 = array($array2Entry1, $array2Entry2);

$mergedArray = array();

foreach ($array1 as $key => $values) {
    $mergedArray[$key] = array_merge_recursive($array1[$key], $array2[$key]);
}
```

This code gives this output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: hi sir i added my output of array_merge_recursive in my question......but not getting my result as i want..plz help ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It takes so much time to find the solution, but i did it...

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array(
            '0' => array('u_data' => array('Mode' => 'Rail','TotalCost' => 150),
                          '0' => array( 'CostSavingRoutes' => 1,'RailCostSaving' => 150,'Costsavingshipments' => 2),
                          'origin_city' => array('origin_pcode' => 2046),
                          'dest_city' => array('dest_pcode' => 4361),
            ),
            '1' => array('u_data' => array('Mode' => 'Rail','TotalCost' => 150),
                         '0' => array( 'CostSavingRoutes' => 1,'RailCostSaving' => 150,'Costsavingshipments' => 2),
                         'origin_city' => array('origin_pcode' => 3170),
                         'dest_city' => array('dest_pcode' => 4670),
            ),
);
$arr2 =array(
        '0' => array('u_data' => array('totalcharge' => 15,'RoadTotal' => 15)),
        '1' => array('u_data' => array('totalcharge' => 15,'RoadTotal' => 15))
    );
$newArray =array();     
foreach($arr1 as $key => $val)
{
    $newArray[] = array_merge_recursive($val,$arr2[$key]);
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
?>
```

This will output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 2046
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4361
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_data] => Array
                (
                    [Mode] => Rail
                    [TotalCost] => 150
                    [totalcharge] => 15
                    [RoadTotal] => 15
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CostSavingRoutes] => 1
                    [RailCostSaving] => 150
                    [Costsavingshipments] => 2
                )

            [origin_city] => Array
                (
                    [origin_pcode] => 3170
                )

            [dest_city] => Array
                (
                    [dest_pcode] => 4670
                )

        )

)
```